Google Drive API `includeItemsFromAllDrives` and `supportsAllDrives` look the same? What is the difference?
Google Drive API Doc says:
includeItemsFromAllDrives — Whether shared drive items should be included in results. If not present or set to false, then shared drive items are not returned.
supportsAllDrives — Whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives. If false, then shared drive items are not included in the response.
Why are both necessary if they do the same thing?

includeItemsFromAllDrives vs supportsAllDrives
Both includeItemsFromAllDrives and supportsAllDrives are parameters used in Google Drive API requests, specifically related to accessing and querying files and folders within Google Drive.
There is limited documentation available distinguising the two, though it suggests that supportsAllDrives is mainly associated with the application performing the request, while includeItemsFromAllDrives is associated with the result that is being returned by the query.
Moreover, it is not necessarily true that they are both required; the need for these two parameters depends on other parameters as well. 
For example, there is another parameter called corpora, and if its value is drive or allDrive, or if there is a defined driveId, the includeItemsFromAllDrives parameter must be set to true.
Another example is that if the corpora parameter's value is set to user, neither includeItemsFromAllDrives nor supportsAllDrives is required.
I suggest playing with the API through this link.
References: Method: files.list , Implement shared drive support 
